# export and import database mysql from java swing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, export

I want to export the data base from my swing app tp make a back up
I was googling about that and the only way worked with me is like that:

```
FileWriter fw = null;                   

String path="C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/tesst/back.sql";
String dumpCommand ="mysqldump -u root --password= gestiondestock > "+path;
// Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u root --password= gestiondestock > "+path);
File data = new File(path);

try{
    fw = new FileWriter(data);
    fw.close();
}catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    Process proc = rt.exec(dumpCommand);
    InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(in,"latin1");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(read);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(data,true));
    String line=null;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        buffer.append(line+"\n");
    }
    String toWrite = buffer.toString();
    bw.write(toWrite);
    bw.close();
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I get only the date base information not the creat table and insert into ....

i only get this informations:

### -- MySQL dump 10.10

-- Host: localhost    Database: gestiondestock

---

-- Server version   5.1.36-community-log

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,    FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
   /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

How to fix that and get all the information on the sql file ??, when i try to export on phpmyadmin i get all the information

the dumpCommand work fine manually from cmd box

and the best way to import it !!

---

#### Solution

I can't do redirection without running a shell, which I'am not doing above.
so i have to do this :

```
 String path="C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/tesst/back.sql";
 String dumpCommand = "mysqldump -u root gestiondestock --result-file="+path;
```

--result-file="+path

Comment: Did you try the command manually? Does it write all what you need? The problem seems to be the command you execute, not the Java handling.

Comment: @gelios i try the cmnnd on phpmyadmin and i get this : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root --password= gestiondestock > C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/tesst/ba' at line 1

Comment: Because that command is a operating system command... not SQL. Try it in a command-line box / Terminal.

Comment: That's why you use `Runtime` class to executing, rather than a JDBC connection.

Comment: @helios its work fiiiiiine  manually from cmd box

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be problem with `mysqldump` command. Instead of this

```
mysqldump -u root --password= gestiondestock > path
```

Try this,

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

Also refer this link,

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Comment: i try it like this mysqldump -u root -p[ ] [gestiondestock] > " +path and i get nothin on the file

Comment: Try this "mysqldump -u root -pgestiondestock "+databasename+"  > " +path

Comment: i dont have a pass word for my data base gestiondestock is the name of my database

Comment: i try to remove the -p "mysqldump -u root gestiondestock > " +path" and i get the seem file

Comment: Try this, Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -proot ABC --result-file=D:\\COMP.ccm"); refer this discussion, http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237159-mysqldump-not-working-with-runtimegetruntimeexec/